# Implementing SSML in Alexa Example

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a modified version of the example trivia game skill with Alexa. Certain words in the questions can't be pronounced properly so I would like to implement an SSML phoneme spelling for those words. However adding in the full pecan style command breaks the message as the code sees it as unbalancing brackets, but not enclosing it in quotations creates an unresolved regular expression. Does anyone have any recommendations how I can include it as x-sampa SSML while still keeping it as the currently implemented var? Here is an example of how it is currently breaking.

```
{
    "Test question 1?": [
        "Answer 1",
        "<phoneme alphabet="x-sampa" ph="EksIlUs">Exilus</phoneme> Adapter",
        "Answer 3",
        "Answer 4"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely the fact that you're wrapping your SSML string in double quotes, but then also including non-escaped double quotes in the SSML itself. To solve this, try either replacing the quotes in the SSML with single quotes, or escaping them with the backslash character like this:

```
{
    "Test question 1?": [
        "Answer 1",
        "<phoneme alphabet=\"x-sampa\" ph=\"EksIlUs\">Exilus</phoneme> Adapter",
        "Answer 3",
        "Answer 4"
    ]
},
```

If you look at the [example Alexa skills which use SSML](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js/blob/master/samples/wiseGuy/src/index.js), you'll see that that's how they're handling quotes:

```
speechText = "That's not how knock knock jokes work! <break time=\"0.3s\" /> "
                + "Knock knock!";
```